# Can the settings chosen in the Quasar CLI when creating a new project be changed later?

Tags: quasar-framework

I'm creating a new Quasar project via the Quasar CLI and it's asking me a bunch of questions about how I'd like the project to work (e.g. what kind of SCSS preprocessor I want to use), and I'm not sure what the best answers are.  I suspect I might want to change some of my answers later, but the documentation doesn't seem to explain whether that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify or change any parameters and settings at any time in the `quasar.config.js` file